# Issue with dates when displaying on Page

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, date

[image: This is what shows up on the Page. Note the Birth Date on the left side of the page]
[image: Please note the birth_date value from the database.]

The issue I have is the following:
When I display dates on the page, they show up 1 day less than what is stored on the database. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed how the dates in the database are 1984-12-30 00:00:00 meaning its at the start of the 30th of December but for the Timezone that's +2. In the settings.py for my project I noticed the TimeZone is UTC (which is +0), meaning that that DateTime at UTC was actually 1984-12-30 22:00:00 (2 hours behind).

I fixed this issue by changing the TimeZone for my Django server to a +2 Timezone, so the dates are represented properly.

[image: The fix I made in settings.py]

EDIT: typos